# Bind a click to a dynamic button with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to create a button that has a jQuery click on the fly. After the user is done and hit the button I want to destroy the button and the jQuery click until a time I need it recreated.

I am not sure how to do this in jQuery. I know `jQuery.live` is an option but I am not sure if this would be better or worse then the way I want to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Live would work just fine. If you'd like to avoid using live, you can wire up the the new button as you add it to the DOM.

```
function addNewButton() {
  $("sweet_selector_here").append("<input type='button' id='sweetness' value='press me, i am awesome' />");
  $("#sweetness").click(function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
}
```

With live it becomes this:

```
function addNewButton() {
  $("sweet_selector_here").append("<input type='button' id='sweetness' value='press me, i am awesome' />");
}

$("#sweetness").live("click", function() {
  $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Does live come with any performance problems if you start using them to much?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.  Change html in strings appropriately:

```
   $('#targetdiv').append( $("<div>foobar</div>").click( function(evt) { $(this).remove(); }))
```

Here's a [demo site](http://jsbin.com/isowu/edit) showing it in action.

Comment: I tried something like that with chaining but it did not work. I tried to put a alert box o n click it never would do anything.

Comment: when I try the demo and click the button nothing happens.

Comment: weird. works for me in FF and IE.  http://jsbin.com/isowu  No errors anything in console?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to post to such an old and answered question. I had a similar problem and this answer helped me but didn't get me quite there. After trial and error... Here's my practical solution for adding areas to web page and removing them. I use it with dynamic form fields but your needs may vary.

Here's part of the form in the static portion of the page.

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Email-tauluun</legend>
    <a class="button_ajax email-add">Add new area</a>
    <p>
      <span class="email_original_area">
        <label>Email:
          <input type="text" name="emails[]" id="email0" />
        </label>
      </span>

      <!--Below we add some more areas-->
      <span id="email_add_area"></span>
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

Then we need some JavaScript functions. These ones use jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//we need a counter for dynamic fields
var cnt=0;

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.email-add').click(function(){

  cnt += 1; //let's count...

  $('#email_add_area').append(
    '<span class="dynExtra"><br /><label>Email: ' +
    '<input type="text" name="emails[]" id="email' + cnt + '" /></label>' +
    '</span>'
  );

    //this function creates a button for newly created area
    //must be done after the creation of the area
    addRemover();
  });
});

function addRemover() {
  //appends remove button to the last created area
  $('<a class="button_ajax dynExtra-clear" name="dynExtra-clear">Remove area ' + cnt + '</a>').appendTo('#email_add_area');

  //remove the clicked button and it's previous sibling
  $('.dynExtra-clear').click(function(){
  $(this).prev().remove();
  $(this).remove();
  });
}

</script>
```

Hopefully this helps someone and I didn't forget anything.