# add an onclick event to a dynamically created linkbutton

Tags: c#, asp.net

What I'm trying to accomplish is to set my dynamically created linkbutton with a onClick command so when click it will run a method in the code behind. This is my code:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadLeftSide();
}

private void LoadLeftSide()
{
    string filepath = Server.MapPath("DataSource.xml");
    List<Post> list = PostHelper.GetAllPosts(filepath);
    HtmlTable table = FindControl("tbl") as HtmlTable;

    HtmlTableRow hearderrow = new HtmlTableRow();
    HtmlTableCell heardercell = new HtmlTableCell();     

    heardercell.InnerText = "Posts:";       
    hearderrow.Cells.Add(heardercell);
    table.Rows.Add(hearderrow);

    foreach (Post p in list)
    {
        HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();
        HtmlTableCell cell1 = new HtmlTableCell();

        LinkButton lnkPost = new LinkButton();
        lnkPost.ID =string.Format("{0}" ,Guid.NewGuid());
        lnkPost.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
        lnkPost.Text = p.Title;
       // lnkPost.CommandName = p.Id.ToString();
       // lnkPost.CommandArgument = p.Id.ToString();
        //lnkPost.Command += new CommandEventHandler(this.onLinkClick);
        lnkPost.Click += new EventHandler(this.onLinkClick);   

        cell1.Controls.Add(lnkPost);            
        row.Cells.Add(cell1);
        table.Rows.Add(row);

    }
    table.DataBind();

}

protected void onLinkClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filepath = Server.MapPath("DataSource.xml");
    int id = 1;
    Post post=PostHelper.GetPostById(id, filepath);
    lblDescription.Text = post.Description;
}
```

Comment: you don't actually need to put "asp.net" in the title of your question, since you've got it in the tags.

Comment: And .... What's the question ?

Comment: I want to know how to add onclick event for those linkbuttons and how the events would get fired on pageInit event.Please help

Answer (score 2):

Create all dynamic links in **Page_PreInit** handler and recreated the same hierarchy on every page post back. Then *ASP.NET* will be able to process *OnClick* event of the dynamic link.
And you do not need this

```
lnkPost.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
```

Maybe ASP.NET Menu Control will be more suitable? It supports binding from XML with XPath

Answer (score -1):

This example adds a button and sets the clicked function to "remove" which removes the new button when clicked...

see: [Bind a click to a dynamic button with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338713/bind-a-click-to-a-dynamic-button-with-jquery)

```
function addNewButton() {
  $("sweet_selector_here").append("<input type='button' id='sweetness' value='press me, i am awesome' />");
  $("#sweetness").click(function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
}
```