# jQuery manage table data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I get some bug trying to manage table data (with the available languages). Here is what I have:

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="add_language" value="Add Language" />
    <table>
        <tbody id="languages">
                                            <tr>
                            <td><div class="input text"><input type="text" id="Setting3Value3Language" rel="" value="English" name="data[Setting][3][value][3][language]"/></div></td>
                            <td><div class="input text"><input type="text" id="Setting3Value3Alias" rel="" value="eng" name="data[Setting][3][value][3][alias]"/></div></td>
                            <td/>
                            <td><button class="delete-lang">Delete</button></td>
                        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

And jQuery:

```
$("#add_language").click(function(){
    var langId = langId + 1;
    var row ='<tr><td><div class="input text"><input type="text" id="Setting3Value'+langId+'Language" rel="" value="" name="data[Setting][3][value]['+langId+'][language]"/></div></td><td><div class="input text"><input type="text" id="Setting3Value'+langId+'Alias" rel="" value="" name="data[Setting][3][value]['+langId+'][alias]"/></div></td><td></td><td><button class="delete-lang ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title="Delete"><span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-trash"/><span class="ui-button-text">Delete</span></button></td></tr>';
    $('#languages').append(row);
     return false;
});

$( ".delete-lang" ).button({
            icons: {
                primary: "ui-icon-trash"
            },
            text: false
        });

$( ".delete-lang" ).click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('tr').first().remove();
});
```

For the moment it is working except that for the delete button - when deleting a row that just has been inserted I get the form submited, it does not run `event.preventDefault();` for the newly added row and submits the form. How to fix this?

Also I should add some kind of sorting the rows but also sorting them the `name` value inside the inputs should change. How to make the `sortable` event to change the input names?

I am not sure that this is the best way for managing the data inside a table but if there is better and easy one - please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For rows that are added dynamically (ie. not available to the DOM on page load) you need to delegate the events to a static parent element. If you're using jQuery 1.6 or older, you use `delegate()`, 1.7 or newer, you use `on()`.

Try this:

```
$("#languages").delegate(".delete-lang", "click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('tr').first().remove();
});
```

or in jQ1.7:

```
$("#languages").on("click", ".delete-lang", function(event) { 
    // rest of your code....
```

This is assuming that the `tbody#languages` element in your code is not appended via jQuery. If it is, try a different selector.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rory for the delegate function. It will help me in the future.

Constantin.FF. Check out this question if it helps you. I wanted to avoid using of Live function so I did things a little bit differently than the already accepted answer suggested.
[Bind a click to a dynamic button with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338713/bind-a-click-to-a-dynamic-button-with-jquery/9400988#9400988)